# Android Telling how much time a user has been playing

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a Game, and i want to measure the time that a user has been playing.

In the game activity, I have two long variables,

```
static long stopTime = 0;
static long startTime = -99;
```

I have tried to set the starting time in `onResume()` and ending time in `onPause()` like this:

onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    stopTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
    Log.d("OnPause","stopTime: "+stopTime);
}
```

onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (startTime == -99)
    {
        startTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
        Log.d("OnPause","THIS IS RESUME : startTime: "+startTime);
    }
}
```

When I initiate `startTime` at first i give it a value of -99 so only if this is it's value in `onResume` I update it's value to currentmillis.

Then pass a long which is `stopTime - startTime` with
`putExtra("totalTime", this.stopTime - this.startTime);` to another activity which gets this value and presents it to the user. i do this, using a method called moveToEndScreen() that's called when the game ends:

```
private void moveToEndScreen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(con, EndScreen.class);
    i.putExtra("err", errTimes);
    i.putExtra("timeScore", stopTime - startTime);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and this is what happens on the next activity:

```
public class EndScreen extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    long timeScore = i.getLongExtra("timeScore",15);
    Log.d("END SCREEN timeScore THAT I GOT IS",timeScore+"");
    float timeResult = timeScore / 1000;
    int errors = i.getIntExtra("err", -1);
    setContentView(R.layout.endscreen);
    TextView stat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errMsg);
    stat.setText("You have completed the puzzle in "+errors+" false matches total, and it took you "+timeResult+ " seconds. Can you do better? :)");

}
```

}

Having Log.d in `onResume` and `onPause` methods with the values of the stop and start times, I see that these methods are running more times than I expect, and give me unreasonable values (negative or zero). Also, i now see when the game ends that the number is changing after 1 sec on the layout from 0 to 3.

How should I go around this?

Comment: As you re-read your post, do you truly believe you have given enough information for anyone to be able to answer you? For example, do you believe someone else will have a finite understanding of what `give me unreasonable values` means?

Comment: Ok, I apologize. I'm learning on the go here. by unreasonable values i mean negative or 0 values. I will try to clarify this question as far as I can, i'm also not 100% familiar with the accurate terms. sorry.

Comment: The vocabulary of terms you're using is not so much the issue... the issue is you cannot hope for a useful answer unless you've provided useful information -- as complete as possible. Ideally, you want to post a single question, receive a single answer, and have no dialog required in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is have startTime and stopTime be static, so that you know you only have one instance of each of those variables.  I think you are losing state when the Activity is going through it's cycles.

The other issue you may be hitting is that you are calling `SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()` which is probably not what you want.  You probably just want to do `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the wall-clock milliseconds.

Let me know if that puts you on the right track or post some code so we can help out a little more.

Comment: I tried to make both variables static, maybe that is a step towards accurate values, but still i get a Zero or 2 seconds in the next activity. I will edit my question and post some of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Now that they are static, I think you want to reset the start time every time you get an onResume called.  Also, you might want to start logging "onResume" and "onPause" strings during those events so you can correlate what you are doing in your app to when those events fire.  (Also updated my answer with another suggestion.)

Comment: I have updated my question, and put the code there. i will try to use the other method you suggest. but i'm thinking of 2 problams with it. 1) currentTime will just give me the time on system, so if the game has been paused the time that the user was on another activity say a phone call will be included in the playing time, which is bad. 2) why should i reset start time to zero onResume?

Comment: The reason I suggest resetting the start time is because of your first question.  When the game pauses I figured you'd want to keep track of how much time elapsed and present it (or whatever) and then start over the next time.  I think the root cause of your problem is that the "thread" you get in onResume() is not the UI thread that you have elsewhere... not totally sure about that though because it should be the same thread as onPause().  Long story you're right, if you restart startTime in onResume you'll need onPause to set the total to the sum of the newly recorded value and running total